# how to have html tags in laravel template using vue correctly interpreted?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, parsedown

I want to display text that uses markdow markup in a vue in laravel8 inertia vue.

I know how to convert it in a blade template with

```
{!!Markdown($post->body, ['config' => 'default']) !!}
```

but it doesn't work in vue templates.

In order to work this around I transform markdown to html into the controller.

```
    public function Index($id = Null)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return Inertia::render('Posts/Index', [
            // 'posts' => Post::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->with('user')->get()
            'posts' => Post::select('id', 'title', 'abstract', 'created_at')
                ->addSelect([
                    'userfirstname' => User::select('firstname')->whereColumn('id', 'posts.user_id'),
                    'userlastname' => User::select('familyname')->whereColumn('id', 'posts.user_id')
                ])
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                ->get(),

            //lazily evaluated
            'details' => function () {
                $post = Post::find($this->id);
                $parser = new Parsedown();
                $post->body = $parser->text($post->body);
                return $post;
            }
        ]);
    }
}
```

This controller is used to update a component that is included in the main vue. Here is the component's vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container bg-gray-100">
    {{details.title}}
    {{details.body}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "PostDetails",
  props: ["details"],
};
</script>
```

The component is correctly updated on visiting the url but the text that appears displays the html tag as if using a text editor.
How to have the html markup correctly interpreted?

Answer (score 1):

After some searches, I found that

```
<div v-html="details.bod" ><div>
```

is the solution.